# Upgraded Firebase - Now Getting Swift Compile Error

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, firebase

I upgraded Firebase yesterday and now am having a very unusual problem. When I run the simulator, I get a swift compile error "Segmentation fault: 11" The are hundreds of lines of code describing the error, but they are absolutely no help. From the error, the only thing I see that might be giving clues is at the bottom. It says:

```
  1. While loading members for 'ProfileTableViewController' at <invalid loc>
  2. While deserializing decl #101 (PATTERN_BINDING_DECL)
  3. While deserializing decl #2 (VAR_DECL)
```

Oddly, the errors I just typed above are not consistent. The view controller mentioned rotates between the three view controllers where I am using Firebase.

To try to solve the problem, I commented out all of the code in the ProfileTableViewController class, but I still got an error referencing that view controller. The only code running in the view controller was:

```
  import UIKit
  import Firebase
  import FirebaseDatabase
```

(I'm also using FirebaseAuth in other view controllers).

What does work to fix the problem is to hit "clean", restart xcode, clean again on launch and then run the program. Everything will work fine unless I make any changes to the code in the program. Even if all I do is add a comment, the error will reappear.

I don't want to have to close xcode and restart every time I write a couple lines of code, and I am worried that I will run into problems when uploading to the app store.

I am using XCode 7.3.1 and my deployment target is 9.3

Any insight you can give is greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: The *compiler* produces a "Segmentation fault: 11"?

Comment: The issue navigator shows my app name, then a dropdown menu that says "Swift Compile Error" and a drop down menu that says "Command failed due to signal: segmentation fault: 11"

The compiler appears to compile all the view controllers and then there is an error that starts with this:
      MergeSwiftModule normal arm64

Comment: I'm able to recreate the error. The error is created any time I try to reference the database on two different view controllers. I declare the reference in the ProfileTableView Controller with "var ref:FIRDatabaseReference!" and then in the viewWillAppear method I set the reference with ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

The error is recreated when I do that same thing in another view controller. As soon as it's mentioned twice in the program it errors.

Comment: I'm also getting this _consistently_ in my test target. I cannot run tests at all even if I remove FirebaseStorage pod completely. See my answer for what I did to fix the error in the app itself.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I was able to figure it out! My Cocoa Pods were not up to date. As soon as I went back and installed the latest Cocoa Pods in the terminal, then updated the podfile for this app, this error disappeared.

Process:

Open terminal

```
  sudo gem install cocoapods
```

(Cocoapods update) In terminal navigate to app folder, then:

```
  open -a xcode podfile
```

If needed, make changes in podfile. I didn't need to make any changes. Save and exit.

In terminal

```
  pod update
```

Open the .xcworkspace file and ta da!

Answer (score 4):

I was also pulling my hair out with this issue for some time.
I tried Eric Duffett's answer but without luck.

I figured out it was an issue with the **FirebaseAuth**. What I did was this:

1. Remove **FirebaseAuth** from Podfile
2. Update pods with **pod update**
3. Download Firebase frameworks from [their site](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#frameworks) (at the bottom)
4. Follow README file to import FirebaseAuth **manually** in the project (need to import FirebaseAuth.framework and GoogleNetworkingUtilities.framework)
5. Clean - Build and **no more segmentation fault 11 error**

Hope this will help someone.

Comment: Thank you, this was the only thing that worked for me after trying to update CocoaPods & refactoring.

Answer (score 3):

This is/was really driving me berserk.

This code causes the aforementioned crash:

```
func ref() -> FIRStorageReference {
    return FIRStorage.storage().reference()
}
```

If I just use it in a function everything works:

```
FIRStorage.storage().reference().dataWithMaxSize(...
```

Took hours to figure this out. The error message points to somewhere else. This was probably the most frustrating debugging experience in my entire career.

Answer (score 3):

In your podfile you can try to uncomment use_frameworks!

```
use_frameworks!
pod 'Firebase'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
```

Then run 'pod update' in the terminal. Restart your Xcode project.

This did it for me after struggling for two days with the Segmentation fault 11

Answer (score 1):

Deleting `DerivedData` and `ModuleCache`, then `Clean>Build` worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem with Firebase.

Xcode would complain on particular class. Just like your "ProfileTableViewController"
What I did to solve this was: 
Comment all Firebase related imports in that class -> Clean -> Build (Obviously got some errors) -> Uncomment -> Clean -> Build succeeded

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a different solution that worked for me. I had a few custom functions that returned Firebase-specific variables like `FIRUser` to files that didn't have `import Firebase` or `import FirebaseAuth` at the top. I like keeping my data service methods in a separate file, so I just changed the functions so that they returned `Strings`, such as `FIRUser.uid`, instead. This FINALLY got rid of the compiler warnings/crashes for good.

Answer (score 0):

The problem for me occurred when I was explicitly setting the types of the completion block parameters for `setValue`.

```
FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "test").childByAutoId().setValue("test1") { (error: Error?, ref: FIRDatabaseReference) in }
```

Everything works fine when the types for `error` and `ref` are removed.